# What words can I use when start a chat with boss

Tags: work-environment

What's the polite words can I use, I use `Hi, chief` or `Hi, man` or `Hi, boss` or just `hey hey`.

If you're a boss, which words can make you a little happier?

Comment: Hi Ezora, welcome to The Workplace, a Stack Exchange Q&A site. Chatty, open-ended questions tend to not work out so well on our site, since almost every answer will  be correct and we can't as easily vote on them to rank the best answers. Instead, ask questions about a real, actual problem you're facing, which includes plenty of details so answers are more targeted. For more details, please see [ask] and [about]. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you're a boss, which words can make you a little happier?

I prefer that folks on my team just use my name.

I prefer "Hi, Joe. Got a sec?", or something along those lines.

(Of course "Joe" may not work for you)

Comment: "Hey Joe.....where ya goin' with that gun in your hand" is NOT a conversation you'd ever want with your boss :-)